# Unable to add tabs to community using Napili template

Tags: salesforce

I want to show knowledge articles to users of community, by clicking on tabs.
I have tried adding more tabs to community from Manage community ,and have saved after adding tabs. It gets saved successfully but still i am unable to view other tabs on community page.
It will be very help if someone can suggest what part m i missing out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most likely the tab visibility is set to "Off" for the profile you are using. The user you login to the community as, check their profile settings, there's a section called "Tabs". Find the tab you are interested in and make sure it's set to "Default On".

Answer (score 0):

The tabs which you added will work only in SALESFORCE TABS + VISUALFORCE tamplate. In the rest of templates you need to use Community Builder to create tabs.

In Community Builder go to Page Editor(left panel) and then click on Navigation Menu. Now you have Edit Navigation Menu button on right panel. In this menu you can add new tabs to your Community.